# cordova Hybrid Mobile application

Tags: cordova

I am new to this hybrid mobile application ,We are using Smartstore to store application data in the Mobile using local table called soup [Smartstore], I am not able to check the stored data in the soup, there is one option called showInspector() using that we can get that information but that is not working properly.So , if anybody knows please help me out into this , any helpful efforts are appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: could you detail what is the result of `showInspector()` and what are you expecting?

Comment: 1
down vote
favorite
I am working on salesforce application. In my application, i need to store data locally for offline supporting. For this, i have seen some forums to achieve offline data storing and retrieving using sales fore smart store setup. showInspector() helps us to get the records stored in mobile, its just an built in function given by Mobile SDk.